# Correlation between in silico titration and observed expression in microarray datasets

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

The following publication uses a titration approach to evaluate possible thresholds for differential analyses of microarray data. As far as I understood, the corresponding authors just mix a dataset several times with different ratios between the two samplegroups to simulate a titration experiment like the one from the lumiBarnes Bioconductor package.

I want to apply that method in silico, but I am not sure, if this is possible or a good idea at all. Given two groups of arrays named c1, c2, c3, c4 and d1, d2, d3, d4. Can I perform a similar approach by mixing already derived datasets in silico?

By example:

100:0

```
c1,c2,c3,c4,d1,d2,d3,d4
c1,c2,c3,c4,c1,c2,c3,c4
```

75:25

```
c1,c2,c3,c4,d1,d2,d3,d4
c1,c2,c3,c4,c1,c2,d3,d4
```

50:50

```
c1,c2,c3,c4,d1,d2,d3,d4
c1,c2,c3,c4,d1,d2,d3,d4
```

...

References:
Du P, Zhang X, Huang C-C, et al. Comparison of Beta-value and M-value methods for quantifying methylation levels by microarray analysis. BMC Bioinformatics. 2010;11:587. doi:10.1186/1471-2105-11-587. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3012676/

LumiBarnes
http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/data/experiment/html/lumiBarnes.html

Comment: what is the difference beetwen 100:0 and 50:50 ?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I fixed it. 100:0 means the original dataset consisting of both groups against a dataset of only one group. I was not able to find something like "in silico titration" data generation. But I am curious if this was ever tried and - very likely - rejected.

Answer (score 2):

I would approach this *in silico* titration by scaling/transform the array signal (probe intensities) by the desired ratios. So something conceptually like the follwoing:

group1: c1, c2, c3, c4
group2: d1, d2, d3, d4

100:0
1*group1 : 0*group2

75:25
0.75*group1 : 0.25*group2

50:50
group1 : group2

25:75
0.25*group1 : 0.75*group2

0:100
0*group1 : 1*group2

Now for my thoughts/caveats on the process:

1) Scaling the intensities will likely not represent the noise in the array appropriately (Think MA plot). And depending on how you do the scaling you would need to make sure all intensities fall within the specs for detection, e.g., the array scanner may saturate at 2^16, so none of your intensities should exceed this value. Likewise, all probes probably have some sort of minimum intensity (akin to auto-fluorescence). I would expect the distribution of intensities to should not only shift lower but also compress because of some floor in the array detection process.

2)  For the 100:0 you would not want to set the intensities to 0 but either randomly sample the bottom 5-10% of probe intensities or sample the dark control spots on the array to simulate the array noise.

3)There would be many ways to achieve a 75:25 ratio (3*g1 : 1*g2, 1*g1 : 0.333*g2, etc.). I am not sure which would be the best, if I were doing this experiment I would avoid the 3:1 transformation as it has the potential to "saturate" a lot of the probes (see above).

3) Scaling/transforming the array intensities may not work at all because the instrument settings can overcome to some degree the titration differences. For example, if the signal on the array is low this could be addressed by tuning (increasing) the detector's gain on the scanner. Generally speaking when scanning arrays you aim for a few percent of spots to be saturated.

The reason I am suggesting this method is based on the paper you reference. Skimming the M&M, what I have suggested is more representative of what they did at the bench, that is in a 75:25 mix of DNA you'd expect the signal to be 3 times higher in one sample compared to the other. Changing the sample number in the groups is only going to change the how the stats are computed because you are changing the df. And is some cases (when there is only one same in a group) stats computation may fail because there will be no way to get a good estimate of variance for each probe.

I'd be interested to know if this works, sounds like a fun/interesting exercise.

Best of luck

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice your answer. Thanks! I didn't work on this approach for a while. Give me some time to respond.